# Make Timage move down and left 3 pixels when Mouse enters and return to original position when mouse leaves

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe4

I have a form with about 168 Timage objects containing Icons that are user selectable.

I wish to make each Icon move Down and Right by 3 pixels when the mouse is over the Timage object. I want it to return to its original position when the mouse leaves the Timage.  This will add a pleasing effect to the user interface.

I know I can do this in the OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave events and it works well - however I cannot help but think that there must be a more elegant / efficient method to produce this effect for all 168 Timage objects,  rather than creating 168 OnMouseEnter procedures and 168 OnMouseLeave procedures.

Any help much appreciated ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to create a single `OnMouseEnter` event handler procedure and assign it to every component (similar for `OnMouseLeave`).

If these components were created in design-time *(hard to imagine)*, then you can select all 168 images in the Form Designer, and then go to the Object Inspector and assign the events in a single go, as Remy Lebeau wrote in comments. Alternative way - use existing list of components (assuming that owner is form and there is no other TImages on the form):

```
for i := 0 to Components.Count - 1 do
  if Components[i] is TImage then  //perhaps more conditions to separate needed images
     TImage(Components[i]).OnMouseEnter := EnterHandler;
```

If components were created in run-time and they are stored in array or list, handler assigning is simpler:

```
for i := 0 to Images.Length - 1 do
   Images[i].OnMouseEnter := EnterHandler;
```

---

Then you can work with each component using the event's `Sender` argument:

```
procedure TMyForm.EnterHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TImage(Sender).Left := TImage(Sender).Left + 3;
  TImage(Sender).Top := TImage(Sender).Top + 3;
end;

procedure TMyForm.LeaveHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TImage(Sender).Left := TImage(Sender).Left - 3;
  TImage(Sender).Top := TImage(Sender).Top - 3;
end;
```

Comment: @Remy Do you think that example of assigning handler in code is not useful here?

Comment: not really, because it makes an assumption that the user has stored the `TImage` objects in an array, but there is no indication of that in the user's question. And besides, the event handlers can be assigned via the Object Inspector at design-time, which is the preferred solution for components created at design-time.  Simply select all 168 images in the Form Designer, and then go to the Object Inspector and assign the events in a single go.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unless there's nothing else on the form, "simply" selecting 168 components is not necessarily an easy task... doubly so with the *no-undo* hazard of a mouse slip ;)

Comment: @J...: you can always use the Structure Pane instead to select them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Assuming they're somewhat contiguously listed and not nested in panels or other sub-controls.  `ctrl+shift` doesn't work in a sane way in the structure pane, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest solution here would be to create a custom component and to sanitize your design away from such a heavy and flat design-time layout.  These naturally become difficult to maintain and to modify.

That said, **if** you want a quick hack to save yourself a lot of typing and clicking, you can use an interposer class to inject this mouse behaviour.

In the `interface` section of your Form's unit, add the following class above the Form's class declaration:

```
type
  TImage = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage)
  private
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
  end;       

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    { ... rest of your form as normal }
  end;
```

And then, in the `implementation` section, add this:

```
procedure TImage.CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Top := Top + 3;   
  Left := Left + 3;
end;

procedure TImage.CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Top := Top - 3;   
  Left := Left - 3;
end;
```

Defining an interposer like this effectively causes your modified `TImage` class to replace all of the existing `TImage` components that are placed on the Form at design-time.

Note that this example is only for VCL on Windows.  For a cross-platform solution using FMX, all UI controls have virtual `DoMouseEnter()` and `DoMouseLeave()` methods that you can `override` instead, eg:

```
type
  TImage = class(FMX.Objects.TImage)
  protected
    procedure DoMouseEnter; override;
    procedure DoMouseLeave; override;
  end;       

...

procedure TImage.DoMouseEnter;
begin
  inherited;
  Top := Top + 3;   
  Left := Left + 3;
end;

procedure TImage.DoMouseLeave;
begin
  inherited;
  Top := Top - 3;   
  Left := Left - 3;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need a separate `TMyCustomImage` class, the interposer can derive directly from the original: `TImage = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage)`. And your interposer's message handlers do not need to duplicate the original code, just call `inherited` instead for default handling. Also, interposer are not class helpers, so they are not restricted by the limitations of class helpers beyond Seattle. Interposers work fine in all versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Does `inherited` work with non virtual methods?  ....actually, it was easier to just try it - it does.  Learned something new.

Comment: No. But, in this example, the interposer is handling messages, not overriding methods, so `inherited` will pass the messages to the base class message dispatcher for default processing.

Comment: Many thanks to all contributors of suggested solutions.  As for creating 168 Timage objects at design time, maybe I have a little too much time on my hands;)  Once again - many thanks - my application is now progressing well !